# Ruby tmpfs which persists only until execution is complete

Tags: ruby, shared-memory, tmpfs

Is there a `tmpfs` kind of solution where I can write into Ruby's memory which only persists until  that ruby instance is complete.

```
File.write('/ruby_tmpfs/path/to/file', 'Some glorious content')
```

It get consumed in same script like this:

```
read_file_function_i_cannot_change_which_expects_file_path('/ruby_tmpfs/path/to/file')
```

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there a `tmpfs` kind of solution where I can write into Ruby's memory which only persists until that ruby instance is complete.

> tmpfs is a temporary file storage paradigm implemented in many Unix-like operating systems. It is intended to appear as a mounted file system, but data is stored in volatile memory instead of a persistent storage device.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs

I've never heard of such a feature in Ruby or its stdlib.

Searching for "ruby in-memory file" revealed [memfs](https://github.com/simonc/memfs), which I have never heard of before today, but sounds relevant.

> MemFs is an in-memory filesystem .. intended for tests but you can use it for any other scenario needing in memory file system.

Using only the stdlib, [mktmpdir](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-mktmpdir) is probably the best alternative. It will use non-volatile storage, but the OS will eventually delete it.